# Randomising Numbers SQL

Tags: t-sql

I have been able to randomise a date with the following code

```
DATEADD (day, CAST (RAND () * 365 as int), '2010-1-1')
```

I now need to do it for a number between 1 and 7 and 1 and 126.

Can you help?

```
SELECT        'Booking_' + Cast(Seed.Seed as varchar(25)) as BookingNo,
DATEADD(day, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 800), '1 Jan 2010') as ArrivalDate,
DATEADD (day, CAST (RAND () * 365 as int), '2010-1-1') % 6 + 1 as PitchType

FROM            Seed CROSS JOIN
                         Seed AS Seed_1 CROSS JOIN
                         Seed AS Seed_2 CROSS JOIN
                         Seed AS Seed_3 CROSS JOIN
                         Seed AS Seed_4 CROSS JOIN
                         Seed AS Seed_5
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain correctly the next line will be a random number not a date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 7 + 1 AS INT)
```

Where 7 is the top bound of your randomness.

Comment: Hi Matt perfect thanks. If I wanted to add a case statement to the line for example 
case when (select PitchTypeWeighting from PitchType = 4 then 40% of bookings) etc, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: You can just wrap it in a CASE statement. SELECT CASE CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 7 + 1 AS INT) WHEN 1 THEN '' WHEN 2 THEN '' etc etc etc

Answer (score 0):

If you have a number table this is pretty easy, example with the built in number table

between 1 and 7

```
select top 1 number
from master..spt_values
where type ='p'
and number between 1 and 7
order by newid()
```

between 1  and 126

```
select top 1 number
from master..spt_values
where type ='p'
and number between 1 and 126
order by newid()
```

Keep executing the queries and you will see that you will get a different number every time

Comment: Hi SQLMencae I have added my sqlcode into my original post so you can see what I have done.